# Removing matching items from two lists of dicts

Tags: python, dictionary

I need to take two dictionaries and filter out the 'garbage' items that are unrecognized names:

```
data = [
    {'annotation_id': 22, 'record_id': 5, 'name': 'Joe Young'},
    {'annotation_id': 13, 'record_id': 7, 'name': '----'},
    {'annotation_id': 12, 'record_id': 9, 'name': 'Greg Band'},
]

garbage = [
    {'annotation_id': 13, 'record_id': 7, 'name': '----'}
]
```

So in this case I need to remove annotation_id 13 from data.

I tried iterating over the list and removing it but I understand that does not work well in python. I also tried a list comprehension but am failing with that as well. What I am doing wrong? My code is below:

```
data = [[item for item in data if item['name'] != g['name'] for g in garbage]
```

The above code creates many duplicate versions of the dicts.

Comment: What is the criteria for garbage? Is it always four dashes as you showed in your example?

Comment: The garbage list is created with a different function and contains many varying names.

Comment: `item['name'] != g.['name']` should be `item['name'] != g['name']`. Also put just one squared bracket at the beginning of the comprehension list statement

Comment: There are many was to do this. Fixing your initial approach: `data = [item for item in data if all(item['name'] != g['name'] for g in garbage)]`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Simple and elegant way to remove specific entries in arrays of dicts, where `garbage` is a list of dicts entries to remove from `data`:

```
 for g in garbage:
    if g in data:
        data.remove(g)
```

**Input data:**

```
data = [
    {'annotation_id': 22, 'record_id': 5, 'name': 'Joe Young'},
    {'annotation_id': 13, 'record_id': 7, 'name': '----'},
    {'annotation_id': 12, 'record_id': 9, 'name': 'Greg Band'},
]

garbage = [
    {'annotation_id': 13, 'record_id': 7, 'name': '----'}
]
```

**Result:**

```
data = [
    {'record_id': 5, 'annotation_id': 22, 'name': 'Joe Young'}, 
    {'record_id': 9, 'annotation_id': 12, 'name': 'Greg Band'}
]
```

Comment: Keep in mind that `garbage` is a list of 1 dict, not just a dict.

Comment: Garbage is a list so it can contain many more entries. The solution works just fine. It is tested.

Comment: It does, I was thinking that question wanted to match only on an individual k/v pair value rather than the entire dict as an item, so your solution is good as-is.  +1

Comment: `list.remove` is a good method but i never use it in practice, preferring to create new filtered `list` object

Comment: I didn't realize it would match that well with 'in'. Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

You can create a set to hold the garbage names and then filter *data* based on this name set (if *name* is the criteria you need to filter on):

```
garbage_names = {d['name'] for d in garbage}

[item for item in data if item['name'] not in garbage_names]
#[{'annotation_id': 22, 'name': 'Joe Young', 'record_id': 5},
# {'annotation_id': 12, 'name': 'Greg Band', 'record_id': 9}]
```

---

As has been noted in the comments, you can also do `[item for item in data if all(item['name'] != g['name'] for g in garbage)]` following your original approach but would be slightly less efficient due to the double loop which has the time complexity of O(M*N) while pre build a set reduce the time complexity to O(M+N), some naive timing here:

```
%timeit [item for item in data if all(item['name'] != g['name'] for g in garbage)]
# 1000000 loops, best of 3: 1.68 µs per loop

%%timeit
garbage_names = {d['name'] for d in garbage}
[item for item in data if item['name'] not in garbage_names]
# 1000000 loops, best of 3: 608 ns per loop
```

Answer (score 1):

How about a simple `filter`?

```
filter(lambda x: x not in garbage, data)

[{'annotation_id': 22, 'name': 'Joe Young', 'record_id': 5},
 {'annotation_id': 12, 'name': 'Greg Band', 'record_id': 9}]
```